# How do I run multiple java classes through gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I am trying to run a main class and as well as another java class (server) at the same time using gradle but for some reason I keep getting this error when I try to run the Server task.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class task ':Server'
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: task ':Server'
```

Here is my gradle.build

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}
javafx {
    version = "11.0.2"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src"]
            includes = ["**/*.css", "images/*png", "files/*.csv", "**/*.csv"]
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.6'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Djavafx.embed.singleThread=true"]
task(Server, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    description = "Run the Server class"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = Server
}
defaultTasks 'Server'
mainClassName = 'Main'
```

Answer (score 0):

`main = Server` means that the entry point for your `Server` task is a Java class named `Server` in the default package, with a matching `Server.class` on disk.

Gradle will have produced such a file with your setup only if there was a `src/Server.java` file to compile.

Is that really what you meant?

Otherwise the value for `main` should be something like `your.company.package.MainClass`.

In addition the lines

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
```

are not needed because these two plugins are already applied in the `plugins` block at the top.